# Set JFileChooser current dir to remote dir

Tags: jfilechooser, unc

I have to set current dir in JFileChooser to remote dir(windows share), but it doesn't work.

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("\\\\192.168.11.11"));
chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
```

I found this bug description: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=ad25b2513da86b421875051509357?bug_id=6741919, but it isn't fixed yet.
Is it any way to work it around(I can't map that dir)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the file path in the constructor like so:

```
fc=new JFileChooser("\\\\10.16.7.139\\ErrorLogs");
```

it works fine, although it seems like you can't open the root of the server. If I removed the \ErrorLogs portion of the string it didn't work.

Comment: You are right.. I haven't notice this, but I think it solves my problem. Thank you.